# How to backup RAID 0 larger than 2TB?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-7

I have a situation. I use 2 1TB drives as RAID 0 for my C drive, but when I make a windows **image** backup to a single drive, I got an I/O error which means that the drive I'm trying to back up can't be bigger than 2TB. Because windows can handle drives bigger than 2 TB, but the Windows backup utility won't, that's because of limitation of VHD file that can be exceeded 2T.

I did some research, there are 2 ways to do it.

1. re-format the RAID as 512B / sector instead of 4K
2. Create multiple partitions in that RAID 0.
3. 3rd party tools , like Acronis.

Is there other way to do it? 
Is there any problem when I restore the Image backup RAID 0 from a single drive?

Comment: Why are you using RAID-0 on a server? Hate your data much?

Comment: There are *lots* of ways to do backups. Easiest here would be something like xcopy or rsync that simply copies the files from one disk to another. Can you update your question with your particular requirements that might make some solutions invalid for your needs?

Comment: @ Evan Anderson This is a special server for only one user working remotely on Graphic things. It must be set to that way to increase performance for 3D job.

Comment: Consider upgrading to an operating system that is not so ancient. The more modern version does use a vhdx file that can handle larger sized - at the time of 2008 / 2008r2 that was simply not seen as a serious issue. YOu outlived that.

Comment: @ Kromey Like I mentioned in question, I m doing system IMAGE backup, i need to create an image of OS.

Comment: @rootloop Time for you to upgrade.  Start with a newer version of Windows, and use SSDs instead of RAID0.  Problem solved.  And, by the way, doing backups by taking monolithic, 2TB images of servers is not a good approach, so find a better approach to your backups while you're upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rootloop: If you have 4 bays/drives available, then I'd run RAID 10 instead, if, as you say above, you are worried about performance/response times for the applications they are using.

Almost anything that involves changing the sector size could cause you even bigger problems later if you don't get it right and you do it while data is on the disk, performance being a concern in your case.

I'd say make backup sets for specific folders inside the root of this drive that go together, then run those as separate scheduled tasks, as that will make things a little more mobile that a 2TB single disk image. So, you have like 4 or 5 directories of data backed up, instead of that single image. So then you'd have (User docs, shared docs, email, etc. or something like that as your backup archives)

What hardware is this on, out of curiosity? Because, like I said above, if you have two more bays, and ports on the motherboard, you'd be well served to run RAID10. Obviously, make sure the RAID controller you are using supports it before making any changes.

Comment: Although RAID 1+0 would be an obvious improvement, it is worth re-emphasising for the author's benefit that [RAID is not a backup](http://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup)!